# Waiting for Several CSV files to load with Papaparse

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I have been trying to load several CSV files before running the code on my page as it uses the data from the CSV files. I have used PAPAPARSE.js as a library to help me with this and I have come up with the following solution.

```
function loadData(){
    console.log("Loading Data!")
    loadNodeData();
    loadEdgeData();
    loadHeadendData();
    setup();
}

function loadNodeData(){    
    Papa.parse("Data/CSV1.csv", {
        download: true,
        step: function(row) {
            NodeData.push(row.data)
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log("Loaded Node Data!");
            load1 = true;
        }
    });
}
function loadEdgeData(){    
    Papa.parse("Data/CSV2.csv", {
        download: true,
        step: function(row) {
            EdgeData.push(row.data)
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log("Loaded Edge Data!");
            load2 = true;
        }
    });
}
function loadHeadendData(){ 
    Papa.parse("Data/CSV3.csv", {
        download: true,
        step: function(row) {
            HeadendArr.push(row.data)
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log("Loaded Headend Data!");
            load3=true;
        }
    });
}

function setup() {
    intervalID = setInterval(isDataLoaded,100)
}

function isDataLoaded(){
    //Attempt to setup the page, this will only work if the data iss loaded.
    if(load1 && load2 && load3){
        console.log("LOADED");      
        _setupSearchOptions();
    }
}
```

I have this following setup, however i don't know if this is the best way to go about doing something like this. the loadData triggers on page load

```
<head onload="loadData()">
```

Is this the correct way to make the program flow?

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach is to use promises.

You can cut down the code repetition by creating one function that passes in the url and step array to push to and wrap the `Papa.parse()` call in a promise that gets resolved in the `complete` callback.

Then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to call `_setupSearchOptions()` after all three promises resolve

Something like:

```
function parseCsv(url, stepArr){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       Papa.parse(url, {
           download:true,
           step: function(row){
              stepArr.push(row.data)
           },
           complete: resolve       
       });        
   });
}

function loadData(){        
    const nodeReq = parseCsv("Data/CSV1.csv", NodeData);
    const edgeReq = parseCsv("Data/CSV2.csv", EdgeData);
    const headReq = parseCsv("Data/CSV3.csv", HeadendArr);
    Promise.all([ nodeReq, edgeReq, headReq]).then(_setupSearchOptions);       
}
```

Note that no error handling has been considered here. Presumably the Papa.parse api also has some fail or error callback that you would use to call the `reject()` and use a `catch()` with `Promise.all()` to handle that failure

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am aware promise isn't available on Internet explorer? And this is the browser I need this application to work, is there something I can do to get round this?

Comment: Can include a promise library if `Promise` object not supported